# closed-form convolution integral of two pdfs (Hypoexponential and Lévy)

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, closed-form, convolution

I would need a closed-form expression for the convolution integral of these two probability density functions:

$$p_1(x) = (\lambda_1\lambda_2/(\lambda_1-\lambda_2))\cdot(\exp(-\lambda_2x)-\exp(-\lambda_1x))$$

$$p_2(x) = \frac{C}{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}}\exp\left(\frac{-C^2}{2x}\right);$$

for $x\geq0$, while $p_{1,2}(x) = 0$ for $x<0$

where

$p_1(x)$ is the pdf of the hypoexponential distribution with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$

$p_2(x)$ is the pdf of the Lévy distribution with parameters $c = C$ and $\mu = 0$

The aim is to obtain the pdf $p_3(x)$ of the sum of two independent random variables with pdf $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$, respectively.

$$p_3(x) = \operatorname{heaviside}(x)\int_0^{x}{p_1(t)p_2(x-t)dt}$$

I was not able to get a closed-form solution with Matlab symbolic toolbox, which produces:

$$p_3(x) = \operatorname{heaviside}(x)\int_0^{x}{
    -\frac{\sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{C}\,l_{1}\,l_{2}\,{e}^{\frac{C}{2\,\left(t-x\right)}}\,\left({e}^{-l_{1}\,t}-{e}^{-l_{2}\,t}\right)}{2\,\sqrt{\pi }\,\left(l_{1}-l_{2}\right)\,{\left(x-t\right)}^{3/2}}dt
}$$

Can someone solve it manually or confirm that it does not have a closed-form?

Answer (score 1):

Based on @StevenClark answer, the closed form of the convolution integral:

$$f(x) = \int_0^x\frac{\sqrt{c} \lambda_1\lambda_2 e^{\frac{c}{2 t-2 x}} \left(e^{-\lambda_2 t}-e^{-\lambda_1 t}\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi } (\lambda_1-\lambda_2) (x-t)^{3/2}}dt$$

where $$c = C^2$$

was obtained using Mathematica with:

$$\text{Assuming}\left[\lambda_1>0\land \lambda_2>0\land c>0\land x\geq 0,\text{FullSimplify}\left[f(x)\right]\right]$$
as:

$$\frac{\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \left(e^{-\lambda_2 x-i \sqrt{2} \sqrt{c \lambda_2}} \left(e^{2 i \sqrt{2} \sqrt{c \lambda_2}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{c}{x}}}{\sqrt{2}}+i \sqrt{\lambda_2 x}\right)+\text{erfc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{c}{x}}}{\sqrt{2}}-i \sqrt{\lambda_2 x}\right)\right)-e^{-\lambda_1 x-i \sqrt{2} \sqrt{c \lambda_1}} \left(e^{2 i \sqrt{2} \sqrt{c \lambda_1}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{c}{x}}}{\sqrt{2}}+i \sqrt{\lambda_1 x}\right)+\text{erfc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{c}{x}}}{\sqrt{2}}-i \sqrt{\lambda_1 x}\right)\right)\right)}{2 (\lambda_1-\lambda_1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica gives the result

$$\int\limits_0^x p_1(t)\,p_2(x-t)\,dt=\frac{(\lambda_1 \lambda_2)}{2 (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)} \left(e^{-\lambda_2 x} \left(e^{i C \sqrt{2 \lambda_2}}\ \text{erfc}\left(\frac{C}{\sqrt{2 x}}+i \sqrt{\lambda_2 x}\right)+e^{-i C \sqrt{2 \lambda_2}}\ \text{erfc}\left(\frac{C}{\sqrt{2 x}}-i \sqrt{\lambda_2 x}\right)\right)-e^{-\lambda_1 x} \left(e^{i C \sqrt{2 \lambda_1}}\ \text{erfc}\left(\frac{C}{\sqrt{2 x}}+i \sqrt{\lambda_1 x}\right)+e^{-i C \sqrt{2 \lambda_1}}\ \text{erfc}\left(\frac{C}{\sqrt{2 x}}-i \sqrt{\lambda_1 x}\right)\right)\right)$$

which is valid for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,C,x>0\land\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2$.

Comment: Thanks @steven, how did you get this result? I tried these two approaches but evaluation get stuck for Convolution[] and does not simplify the integral:  
                     
fx = PDF[LevyDistribution[0,l1],x]
fy = PDF[HypoexponentialDistribution[{l1,l2}],x]
Convolve[fx,fy,x,y] // FullSimplify.   
 
ClearAll["Global`*"]
fx=(k1*k2/(k1-k2))*(Exp[-k2*x]-Exp[-k1*x]);
fy=(sqrt[c/(2*Pi)])*(1/((x-t)^(3/2)))*Exp[-c/(2*(x-t))];
fz = Integrate[fx * fy,{t,0,x}] // FullSimplify

Comment: @JacopoLamanna The Convolve function evaluates the integral over the range $\int\limits_0^\infty$ instead of the range $\int\limits_0^x$ so that would be a different result. Using the definitions of $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$ in your question above, I evaluated the expression $\text{Assuming}\left[\lambda_1>0\land \lambda_2>0\land C>0\land x>0,\text{FullSimplify}\left[\int\limits_0^x p_1(t)\ p_2(x-t)\,dt\right]\right]$.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I tried that approach which seems ok since x = 0 is not of real interest here, but I got different results: fx = (l1*l2/(l1 - l2))*(Exp[-l2*x] - Exp[-l1*x]);
fy = (sqrt[c/(2*Pi)])*(1/((x - t)^(3/2)))*Exp[-c/(2*(x - t))];
fz = fx*fy Assuming[l1 > 0 \[And] l2 > 0 \[And] c > 0 \[And] x > 0, 
 FullSimplify[Integrate[fz, {t, 0, x}]]] Result: (E^-((l1 + l2) x) (E^(l1 x) - E^(l2 x)) l1 l2 ExpIntegralE[1/2, c/(
  2 x)] sqrt[c/(2 \[Pi])])/((l1 - l2) Sqrt[x]) which simplifies to (l1 l2 erfc(Sqrt[c/x]/Sqrt[2]) E^(x (-(l1+l2))) (E^(l1 x)-E^(l2 x)))/(l1-l2) for positive parameters

Comment: The last equation is an alterate form assuming c,l1,l2, and x positive that was given by Wolfram alpha. Notice that I substituted C^2 with c in p2(x) for the sake of ease.
$$\frac{\text{l1} \ \text{l2} \left(\text{erfc} \sqrt{\frac{c}{x}}\right) e^{x (-(\text{l1}+\text{l2}))} \left(e^{\text{l1} x}-e^{\text{l2} x}\right)}{\sqrt{2} (\text{l1}-\text{l2})}$$

Comment: Actually the results I got (both the original form with ExpintegralE and the alternative forms with Erf) are not correct: I plotted them with real values of parameters, and compared them to the numerical convolution of the original p1 and p2 with same parameters. It seems that the function provided by Matematica fits well the first part of the numerical convolution (low to mid values of x), but then decays very fast for larger x, actually matching p1(x), while the numerical convolution for large x follows p2(x), which decays slowly (due to its heavy tail with power law).

Comment: Still I don't understand why I got those different results compared to yours. Furthermore, I don't know how to deal with the complex function you obtained, since p3 should be a probability.

Comment: @JacopoLamanna In the evaluation in your comment above you should have defined $f_x$ in terms of $t$ instead of $x$ since you're integrating with respect to $t$ and $x$ is both the convolution variable and the integration limit.

Comment: @JacopoLamanna I plotted all three functions for $\lambda_1=2$, $\lambda_2=1$, and $C=1$ (for which your substitution shouldn't make a difference), and $p_3(x)$ in my answer above actually seems to evaluate more closely to $p_2(x)$ than $p_1(x)$ as $x\to\infty$. Also $p_3(x)$ does seem to look like a PDF and numerical evaluation of $\int\limits_0^\infty p_3(x)\,dx$ seems to evaluate very closely to $1$.

Comment: @JacopoLamanna Actually spending a little more time on the evaluation Mathematica gives me the normal integration result $\int\limits_0^\infty p_3(x)\,dx=1$ for the parameters in my previous comment.

Comment: you are right I forgot to use t when trying your approach. I tested the resulting formula (and the one obtained with c = sqrt(C)) and fits perfectly to simulated data and numerical convolution, so that's it! Thanks. In addition, to solve the integral, assuming x>=0 (and not x>0) and removing the heaviside(x) part produced the same result. I still have some issues in computing erfc with both matematica and matlab for very large values (x>10^3 with l1 = 1, l2 = 0.1, c = 0.44) but that's another story.